# Silverlight Usercontrol in Datagrid does not fire the CellEditEnded event

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a `UserControl` that is displaying in a `DataGrid`. It contains a `DatePicker` and a `Button` that opens a `Popup` control where the user makes a selection that once selected populates a textblock with the result. The `DatePicker` is the only object that if changed will set off the `CellEditEnded` event. How can I get the popup controls `selectionChanged` event to tell the `Datagrid` that the cell has done as edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was putting the `UserControl` inside the `CellTemplate` when I needed to put something else in that for display and my UC in the `CellEditingTemplate`. Now it fires as it should. I missed something simple and I should not have. Hope this helps someone else.